# Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.01 hangs 2-3 times a day

Tags: 16.04, system

We have installed & configure a Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.01 edition in Intel Dual Core CPU, 4 GB Ram & 250 GB Hard drive for our normal internet & word, excel use, but it hangs 2-3 times in a day due to some unknown reasons, so here i stuck & need a help to resolve this issue asap.

So, please suggest me some solutions or steps to diagnose this issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Jayesh C

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with low resource Ubuntu Server some days back.

Somehow, let diagnose this problem.

Optimize the Ubuntu for best performance

Use the following steps:

**1.Try the following command to see the process taken by the users.**

```
$ top
```

**2.Try clearing the Cache**

Every Linux System has three options to clear cache without interrupting any processes or services.

```
$ sudo su
```

Clear PageCache only.

```
# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Clear dentries and inodes.

```
# sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Clear PageCache, dentries and inodes.

```
# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

**3.Stopping Auto Update**

Last one is stopping auto updates of Ubuntu if done this the Ubuntu will not be able to run the update manually too ( `apt-get upgrade` ). You need to reverse this for manual update.

```
cd /etc/apt
ls # you will find the sources.list file
cp sources.list sources.list.bak # taking backup of file
sudo nano sources.list
```

Add # to all the sources of Ubuntu.

This will permanently disable auto update if you need to update the Ubuntu the above process should be reversed.

All the above commands can be executed in a single command too.

```
cd /etc/apt && sudo cp sources.list sources.list.bak && sudo sed -i -e 's/^/#/g' sources.list
```

These are the best ways of optimizing the Ubuntu.